# Laravel update using update method in foreach loop

Tags: laravel, loops, methods, foreach

I want to update a contact's address records.But only the last value of the "$add" array updates the address records.

```
 if ($this->contact::where('id', $id)->exists())
{ $new_request = $request->except(['address']);
        $this->contact->where('id', $id)->update($new_request);
        if ($request->has('address')) {
            foreach ($request->address as $add) {
                $this->address::where('contact_id', $id)->update($add);
            }
        }
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Record not found.'
        ], 404);
    }
```

Comment: please show your relation `address`

Comment: you should provide more details about `$this->contact` (model? query? relation?), `$request` (from frontend? example structure), `$this->address` (looks like relation)

Comment: Because you are updating `$this->address` in `foreach` loop with every iteration the value gets updated - second iteration overwrites the value written during first iteration and so on. Hence only the last value finally remains in the database record. You need to share the schema of `address` table and `$request->address` data for more clear understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$this->address::where('contact_id', $id)->update($add);` line will update all your rows base on your `contact_id` that looks it is a foreign key. So, all related rows will update.

Try adding a primary key to the where clause or add a unique identifier.